# MySQL Query for counting number of recurrence by latest date

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
 client  datescanned  owa
 user1    2019-02-27   A1
 user1    2019-02-28   A3
 user1    2019-02-29   A6
 user1    2019-02-29   A2
 user1    2019-02-29   A1
```

This is my query

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM s1 WHERE OWA= "A1" AND CLIENT ='user1' and 'datescanned' = 
 ( SELECT max('datescanned') FROM s1)
```

Basically I just want to have the count of A1 only for the latest date (2019-02-29).  In this case, it should return 1, now it's returning 2 (picking up A1 from 2019-02-27.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks
Nathalie

** UPDATE 1 **

Now the following working except...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM s1
WHERE trim(OWA)= "A1" 
AND trim(CLIENT) ='user1' 
AND datescanned  =  ( SELECT max(datescanned) FROM s1 where trim(OWA) 
='A1')
```

Updated Table

```
 client  datescanned  owa
 user1    2019-02-27   A1
 user1    2019-02-28   A3
 user1    2019-02-29   A1
 user1    2019-02-29   A1
 user1    2019-02-30   A0
 user1    2019-02-30   A3
```

If there is no A1 for the latest date 2019-02-30, it gives me "2" since there are two A1 in 2019-02-29...

I want the value to be zero since there is no A1 for the latest date only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove single quote around column name

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM s1 
 WHERE trim(OWA)= "A1" 
 AND trim(CLIENT) ='user1' 
 AND datescanned  =  ( SELECT max(datescanned) FROM s1)
```

If you use single quote you refer to a string literal not at a column  name  ..
when yo need  quote for composite column name or reserved  word  you can use backticks

Could be you have based  you query on an invalid  date  (2019 02 29( try selecting for  A3 (2019-02-28) too

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM s1 
 WHERE trim(OWA)= "A3" 
 AND trim(CLIENT) ='user1' 
 AND datescanned  =  ( SELECT max(datescanned) FROM s1 where trim(OWA) ='A3')
```

of be sure simply select the max(datescanned) from s1 and check for real result

and eventually try using like instead of =

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM s1 
 WHERE trim(OWA) like "A3" 
 AND trim(CLIENT) like 'user1' 
 AND datescanned  =  ( SELECT max(datescanned) FROM s1 where trim(OWA) ='A3')
```

Comment: Best to just always use backticks from the start.

Comment: Thx for the note, however, I get 0 as count...that's strange...if I remove the last AND (AND datescanned....)  I get the count of all A1 ( = 2 ) ... adding it back give me 0 ... something wrong with the last line?

Comment: which data type is the column datescann ed ?? anyway answer updated .. adding trim for remove hidden space too  ... PS  ... 2019 there is not 02 29

Comment: data type for all is varchar ...only datescanned is type "date"

Comment: then 2019 02 29 is an invalid date  .. check better  .. i have addet a simple test too

Comment: show me the exact result for  select max(datescanned) from s1

Comment: Almost there... if I put only 1 x A1 for the latest date I get 1... All good... However, If I put no A1 for the latest date but already have A1 in older date.. I get the count of older recurrence... If there are no A1 for 2019-02-29, it should be 0 .. not counting the older ones